# Calling a USSD number without opening the phone app in Android

Tags: android, ussd

I am trying to call a USSD number from my application like this:

```
Uri u = Uri.fromParts("tel", "*110#", "");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, u);
startActivity(i);
```

This makes the phone app launch and call the number.

What I want is to call the USSD number without opening the phone app or **atlease open it up in the background.**

If the user is doing something, then he should not be disturbed. Only a notification must be generated.

*any suggestions?*

Comment: hey can you mark my answer as the correct answer since now its possible because the current correct answer says its not possible which it is now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is possible now since android O(api 26) with `sendUssdRequest()` check the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#sendUssdRequest(java.lang.String,%20android.telephony.TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback,%20android.os.Handler)