# Android studio Action call to run USSD codes

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, ussd

By using an app I want to run a USSD code, but the problem is it doesn't recognize the "#" symbol.
If I want to run "*100#" it recognize the input only as "*100". How to add the "#". and what is the reason to not recognize that?

Here is my code ...

```
  checkBalance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);


            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*100#"));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mobitelPage.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(i);



        }
    });
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35547547/4768284).

Comment: USSD codes are not supported in Android.  There is no reliable way to do it that will work on all devices.  Nor should you really be using them anyway-  USSD were a hack that existed before data plans.  These days you should call a webservice instead.

Comment: Is there a way to put a '#' . Why the whole string cannot be taken here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.Use `Uri.encode("#")`:

```
    String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*100"+encodedHash));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `Uri.encode("YOUR USSD CODE")` in `Uri.Parse()`.

Example:

```
Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("*100#"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference between MMI and USSD codes.
USSD are executed as soon as the final "#" is entered while MMI codes require a click on the "Call" button.

IMPORTANT : In all cases, "#" must be changed to its "%23" ASCII value.

1- MMI codes work with the *android.intent.action.DIAL* action.
Here is a Command line example for MMI code *#43# :

```
    adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:*%2343%23
```

Will trigger interaction between device and network to report Call waiting status and display the toast "Call Waiting / The service is activated"   (or .. is not ..).

In your code; something like this will work :

```
    DeviceManipulations.call(phoneNumber.replace("#", "%23"));
```

2- USSD fail when used with CALL action. Use *android.intent.action.DIAL*. Plus, it  takes a few tricks :

With command line, you must put the code between **double quotes**.
Example for MMI code *#06# :

```
    adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL -d tel:"*%2306%23"
```

This displays the Device Information popup.

With my *DeviceManipulations* code, using DIAL with "*%2306%23" leaves the dialer opened with the code but the execution does not start.  Workaround is to do it in two parts : DIAL without the last "#" :

```
    int intlong = codeUSSD.length();
    codeUSSD = codeUSSD.substring(0, (intlong-1));
    DeviceManipulations.dial(codeUSSD.replace("#", "%23"));
```

..  followed with "input keyevent" for the last "#" :

```
    DeviceManipulations.customExec("adb shell input keyevent 18");
```

I suppose that sending every single caracter with "intput keyevent" method would work best but the above is a shortcut.

Note : The "input keyevent 18" does not trigger action with Samsung devices.  Those have a different dialer than Google's.  I have to use an Appium interaction with those.

Answer (score 0):

The **short** answer for the question is :

"#" must be changed to its "%23" ASCII value.

See my detailed answer for more ;)